# Accessibility Levels: What is the difference between protected and private

Tags: c#, oop

Could you please help me to understand the difference from a private method and a protected one.
Following http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2%28v=VS.71%29.aspx
I am not able to understand it, specially the phrase "Private: Access is limited to the containing type."

Thanks for your help. Bye!

Comment: Hi, I apologize i made a mistake .. I would like to know protected vs private

Comment: Well, it has nothing to do with ASP.NET

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
class Test
{
  private method myMethod()
   {}
  protected method myprotectedMethod()
   {}
}


class ChildTest : Test
{
  public method useProtectedBaseMethod ()
  {
     this.myProtectedMethod(); // this is ok
     this.myMethod(); // this is NOT ok. will throw an Error
  }
}

class outsider
{
  Test  objTest = new Test();
  objTest.myProtectedMethod(); // throws an error as it is not accessible
  objTest.myMethod(); // throws an error as it is not accessible
}
```

Comment: @GIbboK - Glad to be of use :-)

Answer (score 2):

A private member is only accessible (visible) to the "containing type", that is to the class itself.

A protected member is accessible to the containing class and derived classes

Comment: Just to make it clear to me. A protected member is accessible more widely that a private??

Answer (score 1):

**private** - only visible in the class' scope

**protected** - visible to inheritors of the class.

**protected** may be combined with **internal** : A class member is then visible within the same assembly or in any other if you inherit from the class in question.

Comment: Wrong – `protected internal` means that it is accessible from the same assembly **or** from inheritors.

Comment: svick is right...protected internal does not mean you only allow inheritance in the same assembly.

Comment: yup, true, looks like I wasn't paying attention.